# set an expiration time for document node.js mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

so i know there is something called TTL in mongo but i dont think it will work for what i want to do, i want to set a document from my schema where the default value is basic but when the customer pays his membership i want to set it to "plus" i did that query in my controller, but i want to know if there is a way to make this document when the value is "plus" to have an expiration time, like 1 week or 1 month, and when the time is out set it again to basic, there is the schema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {type: String, required: true},
  nombre_empresa: {type: String},
  email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  password: {type: String, required: true},
  tipo_cuenta: {type: String, required: true},
  isNewUser: {type: String, default: 'basic'}
},
{
    timestamps: true
},
{ 
    typeKey: '$type' 
});
```

and here the process when i change his status

```
userCtrl.renderMembershipSucess = async (req, res) => {
  const status = 'plus'
  const status_basic = 'basico'
  const status_user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.user.id, {
      $set: { isNewUser: status }
    }
  )

  console.log(status_user)
  res.render('users/sucess')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than relying on a trigger that must fire and correctly update the user records, store the expiration and check it when determining if the user is plus or not.

For example, you might add a `plusExpires` field to the user schema with a default value of null.  When you upgrade the user to plus, set `plusExpires` to the Date that it should no longer be valid.

Add an instance method to the schema to perform that check:

```
UserSchema.methods.isPlus = function() {
   return this.isNewUser == "plus" && (( this.plusExpires == null ) || (this.plusExpires > new Date())
}
```

Then any time you need to test if a user is plus or not, just call `User.isPlus()` on the user object.

Comment: Thanks for your example i will try to do that

Answer (score 0):

i dont think there mongodb provide a built-in way to do what you want, however you can run a cronjob every midnight to fetch your "plus" customers, check their membership and update it if necessary.

another way maybe to design your mongodb collections to leverage the TTL, you can separate the User and PlusMembership collections, when a user make a payment, insert a PlusMembership data with TTL